# Internet not working in bridged mode in VMware instances

Tags: networking, vmware, ip, dhcp

I need to give my VMware based virtual machines IP addresses so that they are recognized over internet(such that they act as webservers). I tried by setting the bridged mode enabled under Network settings of the VMs but that lead to internet not at all working in the VM. DHCP is enabled as I checked it through `ipconfig/all` on my host computer(Win7).

How do I make these VMware instances available to the internet with fixed IP addresses?

Comment: What happens when you assign static IPs?

Comment: I dont know how to assign static IPs & where to do that..(!?)

Comment: If Win 7 is your guest OS, you can go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center and click on Local Area Connection then Properties and then you want to check IPv4 and assign IP there.

Comment: IPv4 is already checked over there.. & how do I assign the IPs over there? do I need to assign IPs for host as well as the VMs ? how do I do that ?

Comment: Here is a guide from "How To Geek" on how to do that [How to Assign a Static IP Address in XP, Vista, or Windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/) I would still like for you to try to answer all the questions that mastashale57 mentioned.

Comment: After assigning static IP address I am able to ping from host to guest  & vice versa as well..

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a variety of steps for troubleshooting:

- Did the VM's get the right DHCP addresses?
- Are you able to ping the gateway?
- Are you able to ping the DNS server(s)?

  - If so, have you tried to use nslookup?
- Can you ping/connect other machines on the network?
- Did you install any software that would prevent network access?
- Are your guest machines Win7?  Did you configure the type of network you're on?

Just a few things that popped into my head.  Please comment back with any pertinent details so we can help further.

Comment: thanks.. following suggestions by Darius, after assigning static IP address I am able to ping from host to guest & vice versa as well...so  I think I should now be able to configure this VM(ubuntu server) as a webserver that can respond to requests by any computer on internet, right

Comment: now I am able to ping other VMs, host, DNS & gateway!

Comment: Could you please tell me how do I get a public IP for my VMs so that it could be configured on my website's DNS & VMs could be used as webserver?

Comment: Chances are, you have a public address from your ISP, albeit a dynamic one.  Sign up for http://dyn.com/dns/.

Comment: yes I believe I do have a dynamic IP from my ISP.. won't that work? Is the service you suggested to purchase a static IP ?? Isn't that free ?

Comment: Well, here's the deal, in the off-chance that your Dynamic IP address from your ISP changes/expires/is-refreshed, then you'll have to manually refresh all your DNS records which can be a hassle and takes at least 24 hours to propagate throughout the Net.  With a DynDNS service, even if your DHCP lease expires and you're given a new one, DynDNS allows you to maintain connectivity to your exposed services without missing a beat.  You don't have to sign up for those services to host something but they're surely convenient.

Comment: got your point!

Comment: I just noticed that while I am able to ping other VMs & host & vice versa but not able to access internet on VM(though I can ping external IPs as well from there)..

Comment: I am answering your set of questions, since internet still doesn't work! Yes my VM got the right IP (checked through ifconfig), I am able to ping gateway as well other internet sites; I am able to ping DNS server & as well as do `nslookup`. Also I can ping other VMs; I had VirtualBox installed previously but I removed later. My Host is Win7 & guest VM is ubuntu server. VMware workstation version is 8.